# What are the botnets that can be used on tor?

Tags: onion-services, security, circuit, botnet

I am a student and want to study botnets on tor, so I would like to ask what are the botnets that can be used on tor, preferably controlled through C&C. It would be nice to have the source code of the botnet and how to configure it. Or is there a C&C dataset for botnets on tor?
Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Well, any botnet can be used with Tor - because Tor is just a tunneling tool. Actually, some botnets have already used it. The source codes for bot+c&c are available in clear and dark web for free - just make some search ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!